# Interpolating GDP

Tags: gdp, academic-graduate

So I'm conducting a test on the strength of the APT model using data, I wanted to use GDP as one of my variables but it uses quarterly data, whereas the rest of my dataset is monthly. So, my question is: is it common in academic literature to interpolate GDP values so that we have monthly estimates that we can conduct tests with?